# What could be the names of the sound of the water falling in a shower?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

one of my friends said:

"The swoosh of the shower"

I don't really think it fits the calm sound that could be heard when water is falling in a common shower, listening in the bedroom next door.

What word could be better?

Comment: Can you tell us what word you'd use in your native language?

Comment: Generally, we would just say the sound of the shower. There is no sound word associated specifically with a shower, since shower is a sound word.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of suggestions:

> The pitter-patter of the shower.

*Pitter-patter* is more often used for the sound of raindrops, but can easily be extended to include the “artificial rain” of a shower.

> The (gentle) splashing of the shower.

Splash is a generic word for the sound of water.

You are asking about onomatopoeia, and this gives a chance to be creative in your use of language. We don't tend to think of onomatopoeia as being “real” words, and you can be fairly creative in making them up.

> The *shhshhshh* of the shower was interrupted by my husband’s out-of-tune singing.

I've italicised word used as sound.

Comment: showers pittar patter?? The rain yes, feet, yes. But showers?

Comment: Depends how strong the shower is - pitter-patter is generally associated with a gentle dropping of water. But it's easily understood even if it's not terribly accurate.

Answer (score 0):

The sound of (the) water **running** in the shower.
To hear the shower **running**.
To hear the water **running** in the shower, tub or wash basin. For example.

There is no verb for it per se.

Stop running the water in the shower when you are not using it! :)

[The sound of a shower running_Spotify](https://open.spotify.com/track/7dPDnzeeVV87ZM96swNXl8)